# Error: Can't Open Signed Data 'SHA256SUM'

Tags: sha256

I am trying to authenticate Ubuntu 16.06.3 SHA256SUM. While verifying gpg file I get the following error:
"gpg: can't open signed data 'SHA256SUMS'
gpg: can't hash datafile: file open error"

I get the same error for md5sums also.

Verifying by referring this article:

[VerifyISOHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto)

Please help to resolve the error.

**Update**: The issue was with the file name 'SHA256SUMS' it was stored with .txt extension. Without using the extension file didn't open.

The thread can be closed.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: And how are you trying to do this, what command(s) are you using?

Comment: $ gpg --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS